# Parsing multiple JSON files, keeps returning empty list []

Tags: python, json

```
import json    
import sys    
import os    
import glob

os.chdir('C:/Users/Hasnain/Downloads/assignment (1)/assignment/Json_dump')

def get_file(filepath):    
  all_files = []    
  for root,dirs,files in os.walk(filepath):    
    files=glob.glob(os.path.join(root,'*.json'))    
    for f in files:    
      all_files.append(os.path.abspath(f))    
  return all_files

json_data = get_file("Json_dump")    
print(json_data)
```

Comment: The way this is set up is that it's looking for a directory called `Json_dump` inside your directory `Json_dump` and returning nothing. Instead `os.chdir('C:/Users/Hasnain/Downloads/assignment (1)/assignment')`

Comment: You already made `Json_dump` the working directory; did you mean `get_file(".")`

Comment: You don't need the `os.chdir()` if you're going to use `os.walk()` — just pass the path to the directory to your function.

Comment: Not a joke, just a Unix-centric slip on my part. I don't know if Windows has any comparable synonym for the current working directory, but `get_file(os.cwd())` should be portable, at least.